# Red5 application debug

Tags: java, red5

i'm trying to deploy my red5 app to the webapps folder.  But! I've got some errors in my output.

```
    Exception in thread "Launcher:/myApp" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'web.context' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/red5-web.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'clientRegistry': : Cannot find class [org.red5.core.Application] for bean with name 'web.handler' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/red5-web.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.red5.core.Application; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.red5.core.Application] for bean with name 'web.handler' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/red5-web.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.red5.core.Application
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:842)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:416)
    at org.red5.server.tomcat.TomcatLoader$1.run(TomcatLoader.java:594)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.red5.core.Application] for bean with name 'web.handler' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/red5-web.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.red5.core.Application
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:568)
[INFO] [Launcher:/myApp] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1af1915: defining beans [placeholderConfig,web.context,web.scope,web.handler]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@46136
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1277)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:805)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:680)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1132)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.red5.core.Application
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1484)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1329)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:258)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1200)
    ... 19 more
```

After all of that i've got my app folder in webapps, but there is no .class file in the classes folder of my project. So, i can't use server-side app in my client app.
What's wrong?

App was built by default. Here is my red5-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>

    <!--
    Defines a properties file for dereferencing variables
    -->
    <bean id="placeholderConfig" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="/WEB-INF/red5-web.properties" />
    </bean>

    <!--
    Defines the web context
    -->
    <bean id="web.context" class="org.red5.server.Context" 
        autowire="byType" />

    <!--
    Defines the web scopes
    -->
    <bean id="web.scope" class="org.red5.server.WebScope"
         init-method="register">
        <property name="server" ref="red5.server" />
        <property name="parent" ref="global.scope" />
        <property name="context" ref="web.context" />
        <property name="handler" ref="web.handler" />
        <property name="contextPath" value="${webapp.contextPath}" />
        <property name="virtualHosts" value="${webapp.virtualHosts}" />
    </bean>

    <!--
    Defines the web handler which acts as an applications endpoint
    -->
    <bean id="web.handler" 
        class="org.red5.core.Application" 
        singleton="true" />

</beans>
```

And my Application class

```
package org.red5.core;

/*
 * RED5 Open Source Flash Server - http://www.osflash.org/red5
 * 
 * Copyright (c) 2006-2008 by respective authors (see below). All rights reserved.
 * 
 * This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the 
 * terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by the Free Software 
 * Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later 
 * version. 
 * 
 * This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY 
 * WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A 
 * PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU Lesser General Public License for more details.
 * 
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public License along 
 * with this library; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation, Inc., 
 * 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA 02111-1307 USA 
 */

import org.red5.server.adapter.ApplicationAdapter;
import org.red5.server.api.IConnection;
import org.red5.server.api.IScope;
import org.red5.server.api.service.ServiceUtils;

/**
 * Sample application that uses the client manager.
 * 
 * @author The Red5 Project (red5@osflash.org)
 */
public class Application extends ApplicationAdapter {

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public boolean connect(IConnection conn, IScope scope, Object[] params) {
        return true;
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public void disconnect(IConnection conn, IScope scope) {
        super.disconnect(conn, scope);
    }

}
```

I did all of that with Red5 plugin in Eclipse. So... i have no idea what could be wrong..

Comment: Just posting the errors straight-up doesn't really help much. Try adding your code where the error is occurring, and if you're referencing some files (it appears you are), show the framework for your file system.

Comment: i've added more information about that

Answer (score 7):

I had the exact same problem.  Sounds like you're trying to follow the tutorial videos only using the new Red5_1.0, Like I was.  After many days, beers, and bruises from banging my head against my desk, I discovered that if you change your class to "org.red5.server.scope.WebScope" in your red5-web.xml file it should work correctly (bean id="web.scope").  Also, you may need to change your org.red5.core source imports from "import org.red5.server.api.IScope;" to "import org.red5.server.api.scope.IScope;".  Apparently there has been some class refactoring in the newer versions of Red5

Comment: For 1.0 final and a few of the RC's leading up to it you have to use the new packages. Scopes in the Red5 core are in the "scope" package. Lastly, don't use the org.red5 namespace / package space; use your own package for your apps and it should make some things easier

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar error, although when I checked my class was already set to "org.red5.server.scope.WebScope" as mentioned in Ninth Realm Matt's answer. I later found that I was missing the lib directory under webaps/chat/WEB-INF/.

This may be useful if anyone else has a similar problem.